# why am I still getting results as html using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am writing a simple scraper for job postings, but my function `extract_fulltext` which is responsible for giving all the job description, however, I still got `html tags` as a response, so in this case. it is giving me `raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)` , and the full issue bug https://gist.github.com/SkyBulk/c6df488ef53ae6bc62c86670cfbd09ec

```
def extract_fulltext(url):
    html = requests.get(url)

    job_ids = ','.join(re.findall(r"jobKeysWithInfo\['(.+?)'\]", html.text))
    ajax_url = 'https://www.indeed.com/rpc/jobdescs?jks=' + urllib.parse.quote(job_ids)
    ajax_content = requests.get(ajax_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(ajax_content.text,"lxml")
    text = soup.getText()
    return soup
```

```
response = requests.get(url, headers=self.headers)
data = response.text
soup = get_soup(data)
html = soup.find_all(
    name="div", attrs={"class": "row"})
for page in html:
    print(page)
    prefix = ['30', 'monaten', 'meses', 'luni', 'mois', 'month', 'months', 'maanden',
              'mesi', 'mies.', 'm\u00e5nader', '\u043c\u0435\u0441\u044f\u0446\u0435\u0432']
    date_str = extract_date(page)
    s_date = date_str.replace('+', '')
    match = [prefix_match for prefix_match in prefix if prefix_match in s_date]
    if len(match) > 0:
        pass
    elif "NOT_FOUND" in s_date:
      pass
    else:
        self.data_extracted['jobs'].append({
            'job_title': extract_job_title(page),
            'company': extract_company(page),
            'city': extract_location(page),
            'date': extract_date(page),
            'cleared': extract_fulltext(page),
            'url':  [self.urls[country] + extract_link(page)]
        })
```

I expect the output of `{"job_id": "description"}` , but the actual output is an error

Answer (score 1):

You can do your concept depending on this solution

```
import requests,json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req = requests.get('https://www.indeed.com/rpc/jobdescs?jks=80635306093cf18a,7496998d9ee18bdc')
data = json.loads(req.text)
for id in data.keys():
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data[id])
    print(soup.text)
```

**Demo :** [Here](https://repl.it/repls/FittingCourageousExponents)

Comment: it didn't work , and this is similar what I Have been doing , and always return as html

Comment: it doesn't return an html, care to see the log in the demo

Comment: I mean on mine code . I tried to implement , but it always return html

Comment: if you inspect the headers yu will find a response with json content, the key is the id and the value is an html description which must get parsed in bs4 in order to extract the text, and you are not doing that, you are parsing the json object

Comment: first at all , I found the main issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58360799/why-i-am-not-getting-downloaded-the-page-in-the-main-program

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `.get_text()`:

```
def extract_fulltext(url):
    html = requests.get(url)

    job_ids = ','.join(re.findall(r"jobKeysWithInfo\['(.+?)'\]", html.text))
    ajax_url = 'https://www.indeed.com/rpc/jobdescs?jks=' + urllib.parse.quote(job_ids)
    ajax_content = requests.get(ajax_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(ajax_content.text,"lxml")
    text = soup.get_text()
    return text
```

Comment: I am still getting the same output as html